# Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘a -> Bool’

Tags: function, haskell

I want to write a function that returns the longest prefix of a list, where applying a function to every item in that prefix produces a strictly ascending list.

For example:

> longestAscendingPrefix (`mod` 5) [1..10] == [1,2,3,4]
>
> longestAscendingPrefix odd [1,4,2,6,8,9,3,2,1] == [1]

```
longestAscendingPrefix :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
longestAscendingPrefix _ [] = []
longestAscendingPrefix f (x:xs) = takeWhile (\y z -> f y <= f z) (x:xs)
```

This code snippet produces the error message in the title. It seems the problem lies within that lambda function.

Comment: Note that `longestAscendingPrefix`  doesn't necessarily take a *predicate*; it takes a transformer that turns something that isn't necessarily ordered into something that *is*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`takeWhile` has type [**`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile). The first parameter is thus a function that maps an *element* of the list to a `Bool`. Your lambda expression has type `Ord b => a -> a -> Bool`, which does not make much sense.

You can work with explicit recursion with:

```
longestAscendingPrefix :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
longestAscendingPrefix f = go
    where go [] = []
          go [x] = …
          go (x1:x2:xs) = …
```

where you need to fill in the `…` parts the last one makes a recursive call to `go`.